# Powershell Write-Eventlog Linebreak

Tags: powershell, event-log

I'm making a script which searches all Computer with specific Operating systems, run them through a Whitelist and, if there are Computer that are not on the Whitelist, I write an errorlog. The log looks like this right now:

```
@{Name=Computername1; Operatingsystem=Windows 10 Enterprise; DistinguishedName=CN=la,OU=computers,OU=lu,OU=Hosting,DC=a,DC=b,DC=ch; OperatingSystemVersion=10.0 (10586)}
```

But it should look like this:

```
Name=Computername1
Operatingsystem=Windows 10 Enterprise
DistinguishedName=CN=la,OU=computers,OU=lu,OU=Hosting,DC=a,DC=b,DC=ch
OperatingSystemVersion=10.0 (10586)
```

I want to delete the `@{}` and the 4 informations should be separated by line breaks.

My code:

```
$username = $env:UserName

$getad = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 10*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16299*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14393*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*14279*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*15063*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*10159*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*16193*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*17025*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*10074*" -and OperatingSystem -notlike "*LTSB") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows Vista*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows XP*") -or  (operatingsystem -like "*95*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*94*") -or ( operatingsystem -like "*Windows 8*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*9600*" -and OperatingSystem -notlike "*LTSB") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Professional*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2000 Server*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*2003*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows NT*") -or (operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*" -and OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*7601*" -and OperatingSystem -notlike "*LTSB")} -Properties ('Name', 'operatingsystem', 'DistinguishedName', 'OperatingsystemVersion') | ? {$_.distinguishedname -notlike "*OU=Oldwin10-Test,OU=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=d,DC=e,DC=f,DC=ch"} 

$whitelisted = Get-Content "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\whitelistedpcs.txt"

$getad | Select-Object Name, Operatingsystem, DistinguishedName, 
OperatingSystemVersion | ForEach-Object {

   if ($whitelisted -match $_.DistinguishedName) {

   }

      else{
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "OldWinalert" -EntryType Error -EventId 1 -Message "$_"
      }
}
```

Comment: The `@{}` means you are dealing with a hash table.

Comment: try `-Message ($_ | Out-String)` any change?

Comment: its no kind of ordered....

Name Operatingsystem DistinguishedName OperatingSystemVersion ---- --------------- ----------------- ---------------------- computer Windows 10 Enterprise CN=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=computers,OU=d,OU=Hosting,DC=e,DC=f,DC=ch 10.0 (10586)

Comment: so `-Message ($_ | FL | Out-String)`

Comment: On the General Tab its looking very nice now but under details its still not looking nice. But at least the  `@{}` is away. Its still all in one line separated by spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the output to string before sending it to the `-Message` parameter using `Out-String` will do:

for your case I would try this:

```
[...] -EntryType Error -EventId 1 -Message ($_ | Format-List | Out-String)
```

Another option:

```
else{

$Message = @"
Name: $($_.name)
Operating System: $($_.Operatingsystem)
Distinguished Name: $($_.DistinguishedName)
Operating System Version: $($_.OperatingSystemVersion)

"@

Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "OldWinalert" -EntryType Error -EventId 1 -Message $Message
}
```

and if you want extra line space add `n (for new line) on each line end after the brackets

Comment: On the general tab its sorted now but on the details tab its still all in one line. is it possible to have both sorted?

Comment: for the details tab I think it must be one line